# How to measure how many lines are in a user-inputed string in python

Tags: python, string, line

I am trying to get the user to input a string, I then want to count the number of lines they have inputted and save it in a variable to use in a for loop. so far I have tried this:

```
asciiart = input("Please enter your entire ASCII art: ")
nlines = len(asciiart.split('\n'))
print(nlines)
```

Comment: The problem is that the first enter terminates the `input`. You need to use a loop, together with some way for the user to indicate when input is finished.

Comment: The combination of the two questions linked here should help you out @fvw.  Let us know if that's not sufficient

Comment: The solution to the multiline problem involving `sys.stdin.read()` is probably best in the sense that for ascii art you run the risk of interference if you use a special string as an end-of-input sentinel. How do you know the sentinel wasn't part of the art? On the other hand, you can doubtless come up with a sentinel which is unlikely to be used in any art, and just live with the potential ambiguity.